# prepend a table row to a created table

Tags: php

I am building a table from a csv. The csv format is unknown when I open it so I don't know how many columns it will build.

My code is the following and works flawlessy:

```
$row = 1;
$size = 0;
$file = "FileCsv.csv";
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $array_riga=explode(';',$data[$c]);
            $length = count($array_riga);
            if($length>$size){$size=$length;}
            if($length>1){
                echo '<tr><td>'.$row.'</td>';
                foreach($array_riga as $cell ){
                    echo '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
                }
                echo '</tr>';
                $row++;
            }
        }
    }
    echo '</table>';
    echo 'column number: '.$size+1; //aggiungo la colonna che ho creato io virtualmente
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Only at the end of this code I'll know how many columns do I have. What I'd like to do is to add a row to the table with some information inside. The row should be the first row of the table. If i knew the maximum number of columns I'd just add it before starting the `while` but I know it only at the end of the while: The number of columns may vary per row (usually will increase after the first few rows that are header rows)

I know I can add it with js when the table is rendered but can I do it with PHP somehow?.
These csv files are from different sources and there can be headers or other contents that can vary the number of columns.

Comment: There's a simple solution - separate data preparation from data display. Use the `while` loop to create an array to later use in a new loop where you will render the table. When you separate data from the template, it's easy to insert at whatever position you want.

Comment: _"but I know it only at the end of the while"_ Not true -- you know on the first iteration of the loop, before you've output any of the table, which is exactly where you want the new row. You've already got the number of columns in `$num`, so just output your new row after you calculate `$num` -- but only do it once. You can do this by counting rows ("only print the new row if I'm on row 1") or toggling a boolean ("only print the new row if I haven't already printed the new row.")

Comment: @AlexHowansky `$num` is the number of **rows** while I am looking for `$size` that is the **maximum number of columns** generated by my code. The number of columns may vary per row (usually will increase after the first few rows that are header rows)

Comment: @AlexHowansky the number may vary. Usually the first rows are with less columns (some headers). We are talking about bank statements extracted from different home bankings, so with different formats

Comment: OK I see, I misunderstood how your data was constructed. If you're using a table, you will have to iterate the data twice -- once to count the max columns, and then a second time to display them. Another option might be to use a grid system instead of a table, and just output your initial row with max columns for the grid.

Comment: @AlexHowansky what do you mean with grid system? sounds interesting for the final need of my code

Comment: Something like [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/) perhaps might be useful. Lots of ways to do it, and it's hard to make a specific recommendation without seeing what the data looks like, but tables really are best suited if you have truly tabular data.

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I see. no this is the moment where data should be displayed with a table. It's reporting of a bank statement

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use a simple buffer to store the output until you're ready to render it.

- **$begin:** Stores table opening tag.
- **$end:** Stores table closing tag
- **$buffer:** Stores the output of your old "echo" statements and builds the rows within your while/for loops.

The final line assembles these together, and inserts your count row before any other rows from $buffer.

Adjust as needed.

```
$row = 1;
$size = 0;
$file = "FileCsv.csv";
$begin = "";
$buffer = "";
$end = "";

if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $begin .= '<table class="table table-bordered">';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        // $buffer.= "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $array_riga=explode(';',$data[$c]);
            $length = count($array_riga);
            if($length>$size){$size=$length;}
            if($length>1){
                $buffer .= '<tr><td>'.$row.'</td>';
                foreach($array_riga as $cell ){
                    $buffer .= '<td>'.$cell.'</td>';
                }
                $buffer .= '</tr>';
                $row++;
            }
        }
    }
    $end .= '</table>';
    $end .= 'column number: '.$size+1; //aggiungo la colonna che ho creato io virtualmente
    fclose($handle);
}

// I'm using str_repeat to flesh out the rest of the TDs according to your column account. 
// This allows us to create a proper first row with the count of rows. 
// This prevents a misaligned table. Fix as needed. 

$count_row = "<tr><td>$row</td> ". str_repeat("<td></td>", $length) . "</tr>";
echo $begin . $count_row . $buffer . $end;
```

Comment: I am not very fond of string concatenations and manipulations. This code is very error prone. It is better to create an array with the data manipulate it by pushing a first row and then echoing that one. It is more readible and less error prone but this is a valid alternative

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: Yes, an array is certainly a more concise way of solving the problem. Creating output buffers is a reasonable alternative for a quick solution, but it is indeed more error-prone than storing rows within an array and rendering all at once.